# Is there a way to directly edit a remote Linux server's code base through MS VS Code on my local windows machine?

Tags: linux, remote-debugging, remote-server, web-development-server

Currently I manipulate the remote server through bash commands over putty, SSH w/ x11 forwarding and am messing with the web app locally and when I'm interested in deploying to the remote server I push the files over using a GIT repo.

My local machine is a MS Windows 10 with linux subsystem and the remote machine is a linux machine with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

This leads me to my question of is there a way to directly edit a remote Linux server's code base through MS VS Code on my local windows machine?

Thanks!
John

Comment: Consider using `ssh -X` (so you need an X11 *server* on your laptop). Then you can use good source code editors (such as `emacs` or `atom` or `vim`) on Linux (on which you could install MS VS code if so wanted).

Comment: BTW tool recommendations and opinion-based questions are both off-topic

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I understand this, but it is a specific programming problem so I risked it and asked...

Comment: Why can't you install and use  (thru `ssh -X`) MS VS code for Linux? Did you try *well configured* `emacs` or `vim` (you'll need also some extensions or plugins for your particular programming language, which your question don't mention) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks! I think I have enough to pivot to a new direction.  Do you think I should close the question or delete it or anything administrative like that?

Comment: Maybe you might improve the question and explain what you understood

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Boom. Hope it is a little more cogent now...

Comment: I am guessing you could export the remote Ubuntu as Samba, mount this on the local windows 10 and then edit the files locally

Comment: Why not just use git? It integrates with VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, this really looks like an x-y problem. More exactly, I do not think that you really want what you have asked.

In order to edit remote files with a local editor, the canonical way is to mount the remote file system (or a part of it) and then use any local tool. Samba allows to export a Linux folder as a Windows share, so you could easily go that way. The problem is that an IDE will try to compile and run the program locally on the windows system, which is probably not what you want. In addition, you will by default use Windows end of line convention (`\r\n`) instead of Unix one (`\n`), and cp1252 charset instead of utf-8.

IMHO, you should stick to x11 forwarding and use tools directly on the remote Linux box. The only acceptable use case I can imagine would be if the remote was a production system that you do not want to clutter with development tools, but in that case, I would strongly advise you to setup a local Linux dev. system and use it through x11 forwarding.

Comment: I upgraded the X11 server on my local machine so that it could display the MS VS Code GUI.  The specific server I am using is "VcXsrv X Server Version 1.19.3.2".  So I am configuring the remote Linux server on my windows machine through X11 dialog.